# How do I access a variable that is in a class inside another class while using Thymeleaf and JavaScript for input validation?

Tags: javascript, java, validation, thymeleaf

I have class Animal:

```
@Entity
public class Animal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @Autowired
    private Species species;
    @Autowired
    private Habitat habitat;
    //constructors, getters, setters, unrelated variables omitted
```

My Habitat and Species classes:

```
    @Embeddable
    public class Habitat {
    private String continent;
    private String biome;
    //constructors, getters, setters omitted 


    @Embeddable
    public class Species {
    private String commonName;
    private String scientificName;
    //constructors, getters, setters omitted
```

My real issue lies in my JavaScript while accessing the Thymeleaf variables. Here is my HTML page:

```
   <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
   <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Menu</title>
   <script th:inline="javascript">
       var name = /*[[${animal.name}]]*/; // WORKS FINE
       //PROBLEM STARTS HERE
       var commonName = /*[[${animal.species.commonName}]]*/; //DOESN'T WORK
       // var commonName = /*[[${animal.commonName}]]*/; ALSO DOESN'T WORK

       var continent = /*[[${animal.habitat.continent}]]*/; //DOESN'T WORK
       //  var continent = /*[[${animal.continent}]]*/; ALSO DOESN'T WORK

       //FUNCTION WILL WORK WITHOUT commonName AND continent
       function checkInput() {
           if(name === "" || commonName === "" || continent === "") {
           alert("FALSE");
           return false;
       }
       else {
           alert("TRUE");
           return true;
       }
   }

   //EVERYTHING ELSE IS FINE

   </script>

   </head>
   <body>

   <form th:object="${animal}" th:action="@{/inputAnimal}" th:method="post" th:onsubmit="return checkInput();">

   Name: <input id="name" name="name" size="20" type="text"><br />
   Species(common): <input id="commonName" name="species.commonName" size="20" type="text"><br />
   Continent: <input id="continent" name="habitat.continent" size="20" type="text"><br />

   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The "commonName" and "continent" variables are part of a different class but have been accessible thus far. These fields are being added to my database just fine. It's validating their input which is the problem, I believe I am not accessing them correctly in my JS.

My "name" variable in the JS works great and the form will not be submitted when this field is left blank. However, when I added "commonName" and "continent" in the same manner, running the page on localhost shows up as a blank white page. I believe it's the way I am trying to access the variables from the embedded classes.

I want to alert the user when they leave these three fields blank. Can someone show me the correct way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if it is related to the problem, but the fields of an `@Entity` should not be autowired

Comment: Oh, I was taught to do this in my class last year, but only because those fields are an instance of a separate class. Everything works and is connected until I get to my Javascript, that's where the problem is.

Comment: In my (very limited) experience with Thymeleaf I have found that accessing variables directly sometimes causes weird issues. Did you try using the get methods? `animal.getSpecies().getName()` ?

Comment: Just tried it. Same issue. My form doesn't even show up when inspecting the page, it says there is nothing in the body. Then I take them out and it's fine lol.

Comment: I can technically delete my Habitat class and Species class and add their variables straight to my Animal class, but I was trying to be modular. I'm trying to show this off for my potential employer for my first programming job.

Comment: Another "workaround" might be to create a method in your Animal class that gets the name. Accessing methods shouldn't be a problem. I realize that this isn't an optimal solution, but in case no one else can offer a better one it might do.

Comment: Just tried this, and it also doesn't work. Thanks for trying though, sincerely.

Comment: You're welcome, as someone who's still got a lot to learn myself I know how frustrating it is to be stuck. I just checked one of my older Thymeleaf projects and I got one more try: first, use `let` instead of `var`, according to IntelliJ guidelines, that's how you do it nowadays. Then, try adding a "default" value after the Thymeleaf expression, like in this case: `let level = /*[[${village.barracksLevel()}]]*/ 1;`where 1 is the default. IntelliJ won't let me use it without that. If that still won't work, your error might be in another place, maybe the function just doesn't work with 3 params?

Comment: I thought "let" was only for temporary variables inside a function, and var is for if you're going to use them again outside of a function. I could be wrong for sure though. I added default values to no avail. I might just delete my extra classes and put them all my fields in the one, seems easier at this point lol! If it was just the function my form would still show up. Before I asked this question, my function wouldn't work at all because I was trying to getElementById, which doesn't work with Thymeleaf apparently, took me hours to figure that one out. But the form still appeared then